# Having problems in printing numbers in nasm assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am writing a program to take an input(n) from the user and print the nth fibonacci number.
I am having problem with printing the numbers.As i can't print the numbers  i don't even know if there is  a problem with my code.
How can i print integers(>10) in assembly?

Comment: Deal with one question at a time, to get help on how to print the numbers you should reduce the code down to only loading a number into place and then printing it, remove the fibonacci code for now.

Comment: Remember you must print the ASCII character value for the number you are trying to print. If you want to print `'0'`, you must print `0 | 0x30` to create the character `'0'` from `0`. see [**ASCII Table**](http://www.asciitable.com).

Comment: You have to do the binary-to-decimal conversion, convert each decimal digit to ASCII, and then make an appropriate library or system call to actually output the characters.  You have a fair amount of work ahead of you.

Comment: Your question is too broad because it isn't clear what OS you are on, whether it is 32-bit of 64-bit code, and you haven't shown us any of your code. We don't know if you are allowed to link to the _C_ library or whether you have to code all the ASCII to integer and integer to ASCII routines by hand or not.